# I can not synthesize a right click when using SendInput

Tags: winapi

I'm using WinAPI, with C++, I want to make a right click simulation with SendInput, but I'm not sure of what's going wrong.

My test program should work like that: when i press middle button of mouse, it perform a right click.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)     
{
    // Fetch tab key state.

    while (1)   
    {
        SHORT tabKeyState = GetAsyncKeyState(4); // Mouse mid button

        // Test high bit - if set, button was down when GetAsyncKeyState was called.
        if (tabKeyState < 0)
        {
            INPUT    Input[2] = { 0 };
            // left down 
            Input[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            Input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
            Input[0].mi.time = 500;

            // left up

            Input[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            Input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
            Input[1].mi.time = 500;

            ::SendInput(2, Input, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code hijacks a processor core to go in an endless loop, just to check some input. Use a mouse hook instead.

Comment: Why are you setting time to a arbitrary value?

Comment: I wanted a gap between pressing and releasing

Comment: @BarmakShemirani thanks for that observation

Comment: @GugaLoks you cant use the `mi.time` field for that. You need to split the events between multiple calls to `SendInput()` and put a delay between them, such as with `Sleep()`

Answer (score 2):

In the code to set the properties for the second event record you use index 0 instead of index 1.

```
Input[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
Input[0].mi.time = 100;
```

Use index 1 rather than 0 in the final two lines.

By the by, it's easier to write the if statement like this

```
if (tabKeyState < 0)
```

Comment: My bad, I manually wrote this code here and did not notice that error, but the code written on my machine is ok and with the problem described in the post, I am not able to simulate the right click. I already have updated the post

Comment: We can't be expected to answer questions about code that we can't see. Don't show fake code.

Answer (score -1):

I solve this question using Sleep to make what i wanted to do and I discovered that the sendinput was not working cause I was executing this inside the VS. This question can be closed now.

Comment: So close it. Or better, delete it. You are the questioner, you have access to do that yourself.